# nginx with Django Support on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it correct that by default Elastic Beanstalk does not support nginx with Django (or Python): [this FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/) lists nginx support for Nodes.js but not for Python.

There are a few posts on the internet that DO talk about adding support: [here](http://ashokfernandez.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/deploying-a-django-app-to-amazon-aws-with-nginx-gunicorn-git/) and [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/09/14/replacing-apache-with-nginx-on-elastic-beanstalk/) but one uses a custom AMI and the other uses Fabric to go in an manually set up the box. Both of these solutions seem to call into question use of EB and PaaS as opposed to just using AWS/EC2.

My question is, what is the best way to use nginx with Django on EB?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way is to document a manual installation and then port that to Elastic Beanstalk's .ebextensions.

**Example:**

.ebextensions/01_packages.config

```
packages:

  rpm:
    epel: http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm

  yum:
    nginx: []
```

Then you use the other container commands to create your config files, install any remaining packages and run custom scripts.